# Where to find experimental/theoretical value of (charge) radius of particles?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, data

Where to find experimental/theoretical value of (charge) radius of particles like proton, neutron, $\pi^+$, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Try the Particle Data Group http://pdg.lbl.gov/ - this is a standard source for just about every measured property of every type of lepton, hadron and meson known.

Comment: PDG doesn't have it.

Comment: I found $\pi^+$ charge radius instantly. http://pdglive.lbl.gov/Rsummary.brl?nodein=S008&inscript=Y&sub=Yr&return=MXXX005 in the bottom of the page.